# Antlr 4: Method for switching modes in parser

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to build a MVS JCL recognizer using Antlr4.  The general endeavour is going reasonably well, but I am having trouble handling the MVS equivalent of *nix "here docs" (inline files).  I cannot use lexer modes to flip-flop between JCL and here-doc content, so I am looking for alternatives that I might use a parser level.

IBM MVS allows the use of "instream datasets", similar to *nix here-docs.

Example:

This defines a three-line inline file, terminated by the characters "ZZ" and accessible to a referencing program using the label "ANYNAME":

```
//ANYNAME  DD *,SYMBOLS=(JCLONLY,FILEREF),DLM=ZZ
HEREDOC TEXT 1
HEREDOC TEXT 2
HEREDOC TEXT 3
ZZ
//NEXTFILE DD ...stuff...
```

`ANYNAME` is a handle by which a program can access the here-doc content.

`DD *` is mandatory and informs MVS that a here-doc follows.

`SYMBOLS=(JCLONLY,FILEREF)` is optional detail relating to how the here-doc is handled.

`DLM=ZZ` is also optional and defines the here-doc terminator (default terminator = `/*`).

I need to be able, at parser level, to process the `//ANYNAME...` line (I have that bit), **then to read the here-doc content until I find the (possibly non-default) here-doc terminator**.  In a sense, this looks like a lexer modes opportunity- but at this point I am working within the parser and I do not have a fixed terminator to work with.

I need guidance on how to switch modes to handle my here-doc, then switch back again to continue processing my JCL.

A hugely abridged version of my grammar follows (the actual grammar, so far, is about 2,200 lines and is incomplete).

Thanks for any insights.  I appreciate your help, comments and suggestions.

```
/* the ddstmt parser rule should be considered the main entry point. It handles (at least):

           //ANYNAME  DD *,SYMBOLS=(JCLONLY,FILEREF),DLM=ZZ
    and    //         DD *,DLM=ZZ
    and    //ANYNAME  DD *,SYMBOLS=EXECSYS
    and    //ANYNAME  DD *

  I need to be able process the above line as JCL then read the here-doc content...

                   "HEREDOC TEXT 1"
                   "HEREDOC TEXT 2"
                   "HEREDOC TEXT 3"

  as either a single token or a series of tokens, then, after reading the here-doc 
  delimiter...

                   "ZZ"

 , go back to processing regular JCL again.

*/


    /* lexer rules: */

                LINECOMMENT3        :   SLASH SLASH STAR                            ;
                DSLASH              :   SLASH SLASH                                 ;
                INSTREAMTERMINATE   :   SLASH STAR                                  ;
                SLASH               :   '/'                                         ;
                STAR                :   '*'                                         ;
                OPAREN              :   '('                                         ;
                CPAREN              :   ')'                                         ;
                COMMA               :   ','                                         ;

                KWDD                :   'DD'                                        ;
                KWDLM               :   'DLM'                                       ;
                KWSYMBOLS           :   'SYMBOLS'                                   ;
                KWDATA              :   'DATA'                                      ;

                SYMBOLSTARGET       :   'JCLONLY'|'EXECSYS'|'CNVTSYS'               ;
                EQ                  :   '='                                         ;
                APOST               :   '\''                                        ;
                fragment
                SPC                 :   ' '                                         ;
                SPCS                :   SPC+                                        ;
                NL                  :   ('\r'? '\n')                                ;
                UNQUOTEDTEXT        :   (APOST APOST|~[=\'\"\r\n\t,/() ])+          ;


    /* parser rules: */

                label               :   unquotedtext
                                    ;
                separator           :   SPCS
                                    ;

        /* handle crazy JCL comment rules - start */
                    partcomment         :   SPCS partcommenttext NL
                                        ;
                    partcommenttext     :   ((~NL+?)?)
                                        ;
                    linecomment         :   LINECOMMENT3 linecommenttext NL
                                        ;
                    linecommenttext     :   ((~NL+?)?)
                                        ;
                    postcommaeol        :   ( (partcomment|NL) linecomment* DSLASH SPCS )?
                                        ;
                    poststmteol         :   ( (partcomment|NL) linecomment* )?
                                        ;
        /* handle crazy JCL comment rules - end */

                ddstmt              :   DSLASH (label|) separator KWDD separator dddecl
                                    ;
                dddecl              :   ...
                                    |   ddinstreamdecl
                                    |   ...
                                    ;
                ddinstreamdecl      :   (STAR|KWDATA) poststmteol ddinstreamopts
                                    ;
                ddinstreamopts      :    ( COMMA postcommaeol ddinstreamopt poststmteol )*
                                    ;
                ddinstreamopt       :    (   ddinstreamdelim
                                         |   symbolsdecl
                                         )
                                    ;
                ddinstreamdelim     :   KWDLM EQ unquotedtext
                                    ;
                symbolsdecl         :   KWSYMBOLS EQ symbolsdef
                                    ;
                symbolsdef          :   OPAREN symbolstarget ( COMMA symbolsloggingdd )? CPAREN
                                    |   symbolstarget
                                    ;
                symbolstarget       :   SYMBOLSTARGET
                                    ;
                symbolsloggingdd    :   unquotedtext
                                    ;
                unquotedtext        :   UNQUOTEDTEXT
                                    ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lexer needs to be able to tokenize the entire document prior to the beginning of the parsing operation. Any attempt to control the lexer from within the parser is a recipe for endless nightmares down the road. The following fragments of a [PHP Lexer](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/LangSvcV2/blob/master/Tvl.VisualStudio.Language.Php/Parser/PhpLexer.g4) show how predicates can be used in combination with lexer modes to detect the end of a string with a user-defined delimiter. The key part is recording the start delimiter, and then checking tokens which start at the beginning of the line against it.

```
PHP_NOWDOC_START
    :   '<<<\'' PHP_IDENTIFIER '\'' {_input.La(1) == '\r' || _input.La(1) == '\n'}?
        -> pushMode(PhpNowDoc)
    ;

mode PhpNowDoc;

    PhpNowDoc_NEWLINE : NEWLINE -> type(NEWLINE);

    PHP_NOWDOC_END
        :   {_input.La(-1) == '\n'}?
            PHP_IDENTIFIER ';'?
            {CheckHeredocEnd(_input.La(1), Text);}?
            -> popMode
        ;

    PHP_NOWDOC_TEXT
        :   ~[\r\n]+
        ;
```

The identifier is actually recorded in a custom override of `NextToken()` (shown here for a C# target):

```
public override IToken NextToken()
{
    IToken token = base.NextToken();
    switch (token.Type)
    {
    case PHP_NOWDOC_START:
        // <<<'identifier'
        _heredocIdentifier = token.Text.Substring(3).Trim('\'');
        break;

    case PHP_NOWDOC_END:
        _heredocIdentifier = null;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return token;
}

private bool CheckHeredocEnd(int la1, string text)
{
    // identifier
    //  - or -
    // identifier;
    bool semi = text[text.Length - 1] == ';';
    string identifier = semi ? text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1) : text;
    return string.Equals(identifier, HeredocIdentifier, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide me with your insight. I will review it and try to get my head around the technique you suggest. I may come back with more questions. TIA.